# Windows Remote Desktop Service Host

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services

from my customer I have the following requirement:
A VMware host shall manage VMs for application clients running on Windows Server 2016. In the plant of the customer there are 75 operators concurrently working with this application.
Therefore, my idea is to create a RDS Host VM which is providing many concurrent Windows sessions. The operators get thin clients and connect via RDP to the hosrt where the application is installed.

Unfortunately I have no experience how to correctly setup the architecture for RDS Host correctly.
From the application developer there is the recommendation to host at maximum 25 sessions per RDS Host. This would mean I need 3 RDS Hosts, that arrange somehow internally which operator is connected via which RDS Host.

- How is this connection management performed within RDS? Is there a centralized instance managing it?
- What are the virtual hardware requirements for such an RDS Host? Do I just multiply the single session application requirements by 25 ?
- In case on host fails, is it possible to dynamically turn on an additional VM that takes over?
- Is it correct that I need 75 Device CALs?

Thanks for you help!